# Highcharts working only in FireFox browser

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, firefox, highcharts

I am working on Highcharts application where chart will be displayed from XML data.
I have gone through Highcharts XML example.
Please see below links - 
Highcharts How to Use - http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use
Highcharts XML example - http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-xml.htm

This example works fine on all browsers including IE.
What I have done is - 
1) copied the source code of the example and saved into a file.
2) made changes so that the code uses library files (jquery and highcharts) present on my machine.
3) reads the XML file present on my machine.

After these changes everything works fine in Firefox. It is even displaying the changes I made to the XML data which means it is reading my XML data. But it doesnt work in IE. It shows no Javascript error, on screen I can see chart name "Fruit Consumption" but no chart. It is not working even in Chrome. I only see white screen. Can you please help me with this? I even removed the changes to use lib files on my machine. So the code will use lib files web hosted by Highcharts and JQuery and will read only XML data stored on my machine. But it is not working even in this case. I added an alert to see if the XML file was read correctly and it was. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved....I installed XAMPP web server and called the file from the server and it worked...it was perhaps something to do with Google chrome security features which doesn't allow local files to be access by local files...some origin getting set to null issue...now code works in ie and chrome both....:)

Answer (score 1):

I know that if you have to much data that you are trying to push to a Highchart it may not render it at all.  Typically if this is the case it will only show the chart title and sub-title.  Browsers have different levels of JavaScript support.  So, some handle larger Highcharts and some don't.

In IE and Chrome if you view the source and the Highchart is present with data then the above may be your problem.  To test, reduce the amount of data in the XML file and retry.  Keep on doing so until it displays in the browser.

Comment: The original XML doc is very small. But I tried even with just one record in XML and still it did not work. One thing is, in IE when I add an alert to print XML read by the browser it comes correctly but in chrome even that is not happening. As before, everything works perfect in firefox.

Comment: Can you post the view source from IE? It could also be something as simple as a missed comma or semi colon.

Comment: not sure wht the problem is but when I try to post the view source it is saying your code is not prperly formatted although I have done all the steps like indenting 4 spaces etc...